# Shortcuts of Visual Studio (moving From Eclipse)

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio, api, keyboard-shortcuts

I am pretty new to Visual Studio and .net framework and I need some help.

First with VS I can't find the useful shortcuts I used to use with Eclipse such as :

- Importing packages (Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse) .
- Generating automaticly some methods (like equals() and toString()).
- Generating the needed try/catch automatically with the right thrown Exception (no need to write it and search in MSDN for the right exception).

Second, is there any Java-Api-Like documentation for .net framework, MSDN is really confusing and I find it really hard to find what I look for.

Comment: Unlike Java, you don't have to catch every exception thrown by a method explicitly.

Comment: Can you go ahead please?

Comment: Also, check out the excellent ReSharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx), via MSDN.

The ones I find myself using the most often are:

- CTRL+SHIFT+F12 (Find in files)
- SHIFT+F9 (Quick Watch)
- F10 (Step Over)
- F11 (Step Into)
- F5 (Play)

As far as documentation goes, I actually find MSDN to be a great resource.  Sometimes actually finding what I'm looking for is the hardest part, but google solves that pretty easily.  The writing, however, is typically clear and thorough, at least in my experience.  If you haven't seen these, perhaps they will be of some use, particularly the 2nd link.

[MSDN - .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx)

[MSDN - .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx)

I know you said you don't love it, but it truly is the best available in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but I'll try to answer anyway...

> - Importing packages (Ctrl+Shift+O in Eclipse) .

There is no notion of "package" in .NET. There are assemblies that contain classes, and these classes are organized in namespaces. To add an assembly reference, right click on the project and select "Add reference". If you want to automatically import the namespace that contains a class you're using, put the caret on the class name and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. It will suggest the namespace to import.

> - Generating automaticly some methods ( like equals() et toString()).

Just type `override` and hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, it will suggest a list of methods to override (including `Equals` and `ToString`)

> - Generating the needed try/catch automaticly with the right thrown Exception (no need to write it and search in MSDN for the right exception)

Type `try` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will complete the try/catch block (this is known as a [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)). There is no way to automatically catch the right exception, because unlike Java, C# methods don't declare what exceptions they can throw.

> Second ,is there any Java-Api-Like documentation for .net framework , MSDN is really confusing and I find it really hard to find what I look for.

You can find the reference for all .NET Framework classes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx) (here's the [`Object` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) for instance). IMHO it's much more convenient than the Java API documentation, but I guess it's a matter of taste and habit... You can also download the offline documentation, which provides an index of classes, members, keywords, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering,that helped me much.But I dont agree with you when you say there is no way to automatically catch the right exception ,for example (je viens tout juste de m'en rendre compte) VS knows what execeptions are needed when we declare a new StreamWriter.I think there's somehow a way to do it.

Comment: @lemoos: The documentation for the .NET Framework will list exceptions that a particular method can throw. However, the documentation is often not listing all possible exceptions because it is almost impossible to determine the entire set of exceptions that can be thrown. And even if the listing was correct you could still get exceptions like `OutOfMemoryException` and `ThreadAbortException`. Trying to retrofit the mindset of Java exception handling into .NET is probably not very useful.

Comment: Yes - don't assume that the exceptions listed in MSDN are exhaustive; they are not.  They do not list every possible exception that could be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `Ctrl+Shift+O` in Eclipse is `Shift+Alt+F10`. For the try-catch generation select the text using mouse or shift and arrows followed by that `ctrl+k` then `ctrl+s`. A window appears where you can browse what to surround your code block with like `if`,`try` etc.